# Typescript Intface Array with elementd being Object or null

Tags: typescript

Im trying to convert this JSON prototype into a typescript interface

```
{
  "foo": [
     null,
     null,
     null,
     {...}
     null,
     {...}
   ]
}
```

Basically all elements of array foo can either be `Object | null`.
I know in typescript you can have something like this

```
interface Example {
  test: String | null;
}
```

but I don't see any examples for dynamic array types.

Would a better approach be using the `?` instead?

```
interface Example {
  test?: Object;
}
```

Comment: Array with element object or null: `Array<object | null>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aleksey L, it seems that is the correct the way of doing things. To anybody finding this question later the correct interface to model the given json
object is

```
interface Example {
  foo: Array<object | null>
}
```